# Bound the first derivative of the following function: $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Consider a decreasing function $f(x)$, resulting from the sum of two other decreasing functions: $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$. All these 3 functions are positive. In addition, we have $g(0)=h(0)=1$. Further, we assume that $h(x) < g(x)$ over $(0,1]$ . The interval of $x$ is $[0,1]$.

How can I bound (as tight as possible) the first derivative of $f(x)$ ? by bound I mean an upper bound on the absolute value of the derivative.

**Some details**:

- $g(x)=Q_1 (\sqrt{\frac{2(1-x^2)}{x^2}}\,n, \sqrt{\frac{2c_1}{x^2}} )$ and $h(x)=Q_1 (\sqrt{\frac{2(1-x^2)}{x^2}}\,n, \sqrt{\frac{2c_2}{x^2}} )$, where $Q_1$ is the Marcum function of the first order, $c_2 > c_1$ (so $h(x) < g(x)$), and $c_1$, $c_2$, $n$ are positive.
- In case it is difficult to derive the bound over the complete interval $[0,1]$, we can assume that $x$ is sufficiently small, so $\frac{(1-x^2)}{x^2} \approx \frac{1}{x^2} $.

Comment: Quick notes, h(x) < g(x) does not make sense in the closed interval [0,1] if you are assuming h(0)=g(0) = 1. It does however, make sense on the clopen interval (0,1]. Second, are we bounding the derivative in the interval or when x is incredibly small? These are some important things to consider.

Comment: @Keegan  I edited the  question. Thank you for your comment.